# Keep plots and input values when switching between tabs

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I have a shinydashboard app with two different tab panels. Each tab has different input values and both of them generate a graph when an action button is clicked.

Whenever I switch between these tabs, their respective graphs disappear and input values are reset to default.

I want to keep the tabs in their user modified states (i.e keep both graphs and inputs) even when the user decides to switch between the panels.

**Code**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


ui <- fluidPage(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "DASHBOARD"),

    dashboardSidebar(
      uiOutput("mysidebar"),
    ),

    dashboardBody(
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", id = "tab", 
                  tabPanel("Tab1", fluid = TRUE, value = 1,plotOutput("A")),
                  tabPanel("Tab2", fluid = TRUE, value = 2, plotOutput("B"))
      )
    )
  )

)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$mysidebar <- renderUI({

    if(input$tab == 1){
      tagList(
        sliderInput(inputId = "Sample",
                    label = "Enter Number of Samples:",
                    min = 1000, max = 100000,
                    value = 10000),
        fluidRow(
          column(6,
                 actionButton(inputId = "b1", label = "Generate"))
        )}

    if(input$tab == 2){
      tagList(
        sliderInput(inputId = "Weight",
                    label = "Enter Weight:",
                    value = 100),
        fluidRow(
          column(6,
                 actionButton(inputId = "b2", label = "Generate"))
        )}

    p1<- eventReactive(input$b1, {
      #creating a dataframe using input "Sample" in tab1 - Rough example
      df <- input$Sample

    })
    output$SA <- renderPlot({

        plot(df)

    })

    p2 <- eventReactive(input$b2, {
      #creating a dataframe using input "Weight" in tab2-- Rough example
      df2 <- input$Weight

    })
    output$A <- renderPlot({

      plot(p1())

    })
   output$B <- renderPlot({

      plot(p2())

    })
}
```

Comment: Youre code is not working. There are some syntax errors

Comment: In the eventReactive functions p1 and p2, I have just created a dataframe using the input sample from the tabs. I have not written an exact code of this. It's just a rough example for you to get an idea what I am trying to do. I then use these functions to plot outputs for each tab.

Comment: Still, copy your code and try to run it. It wont work. In the ui you mix fluidPage with dashboardPage and in the server I think some parenthesis are missing.

Comment: Ok there maybe some parenthesis missing because I have extracted this sample chunk from a large code. The main problem is that my plots are disappearing and inputs are resetting to default whenever I switch between the tabs. General idea is the same. Take an an input from a particular tab, create a dataframe, and then plot that dataframe.

Comment: Everytime there is a change anywhere within the `renderUI` it will remake the widgets and the outputs, its not a good way of designing it if you need the plots to remain

Answer (score 2):

I'd much rather you use `show` and `hide` functionality within `shinyjs` package like example below, this way the values will be preserved when you switch between the Tabs

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)


ui <- fluidPage(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "DASHBOARD"),

    dashboardSidebar(
      useShinyjs(),
      sliderInput("Sample","Enter Number of Samples:",min = 1000, max = 100000,value = 10000),
      sliderInput("Weight","Enter Weight:",min = 1, max = 1000,value = 100),
      fluidRow(column(6,actionButton("b1","Generate"),actionButton("b2","Generate")))
    ),

    dashboardBody(
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", id = "tab", 
                  tabPanel("Tab1", fluid = TRUE, value = 1,plotOutput("A")),
                  tabPanel("Tab2", fluid = TRUE, value = 2, plotOutput("B"))
      )
    )
  )

)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  observe({
    if(input$tab == 1){
      show("Sample")
      show("b1")
      hide("Weight")
      hide("b2")
    }
    if(input$tab == 2){
      hide("Sample")
      hide("b1")
      show("Weight")
      show("b2")
    }
  })

  p1<- eventReactive(input$b1,{
    df <- rnorm(input$Sample)
  })
  output$SA <- renderPlot({
    plot(df)
  })

  p2 <- eventReactive(input$b2,{
    df2 <- rnorm(input$Weight)
  })

  output$A <- renderPlot({plot(p1())})
  output$B <- renderPlot({plot(p2())})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: This is indeed a much better choice!

Answer (score 1):

The following code keeps the plots and inputs, by using `reactiveValues`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "DASHBOARD"),

                    dashboardSidebar(
                      uiOutput("mysidebar")
                    ),

                    dashboardBody(
                      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", id = "tab",
                                  tabPanel("Tab1",  value = 1,plotOutput("SA")),
                                  tabPanel("Tab2",  value = 2, plotOutput("SA1"))
                      )
                    )
)


server <- function(input, output, session){

  slider_react <- reactiveValues(b1=10000, b2 = 100)

  observe({
    if (input$tab == 1){
      output$mysidebar <- renderUI({
        tagList(
          sliderInput(inputId = "Sample",
                      label = "Enter Number of Samples:",
                      min = 1000, max = 100000,
                      # value = 10000),
                      value = slider_react$b1),
          actionButton(inputId = "b1", label = "Generate"))
      })
    }

    if(input$tab == 2){
      output$mysidebar <- renderUI({
        tagList(
          sliderInput(inputId = "Weight",
                      label = "Enter Weight:",
                      min=0, max=1000,
                      # value = 100),
                      value = slider_react$b2),
          actionButton(inputId = "b2", label = "Generate"))
      })
    }
  })


  df_react <- reactiveValues(a1=NULL, a2=NULL)

  p1<- observeEvent(input$b1, {
    #creating a dataframe using input "Sample" in tab1 - Rough example
    df <- runif(input$Sample, 0, 100)
    slider_react$b1 = input$Sample
    df_react$a1 = df
  })
  p2 <- observeEvent(input$b2, {
    #creating a dataframe using input "Weight" in tab2-- Rough example
    df2 <- runif(input$Weight, 0, 100)
    slider_react$b2 = input$Weight
    df_react$a2 = df2
  })

  output$SA <- renderPlot({
    req(df_react$a1)
    plot(df_react$a1)
  })

  output$SA1 <- renderPlot({
    req(df_react$a2)
    plot(df_react$a2)

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working fine now. Any clue on how I can retain the inputs too?

Comment: Check out @Pork Chop`s answer. The inputs are created in the ui and with shinyjs he is showing/hiding elements. Like that, the sliderInputs are not recreated everytime you switch between the tabs. I think that solution is much clearer and easier

Comment: Just edited my answer. The inputs are retained aswell now, by using another `reactiveValues` object, where the slider-values are stored.